# Github-Jenkins Integration > Error received as 'Last Delivery was not successful. Couldn't connect to server'

Tags: git, selenium, jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I am trying to integrate GitHub with Jenkins to run my Selenium Automation Project.
Here is what I have done till now.

1. Created new Freestyle Project in Jenkins
2. Selected GitHub Project and added repository url under 'GitHub project'
3. Selected 'Git' as source code management and entered url copied from clone address in 'Repository URL' field
4. Selected 'GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling' as build trigger
5. Added 'top level maven target' as build step under 'BUILD'

Went back to web GitHub

1. Went to Settings tab of respective repository
2. Under Webhooks, clicked 'add webhook' and entered 'Payload URL' as 'http://{my machine ip}:8080/github-webhook/'
3. Went back to source code tab and edited text.

In this case, I expected my jenkins build to get triggered but nothing happened.
When checked webhooks, there is red error icon with note 'Last Delivery was not successful. Couldn't connect to server'

If I try to build same project directly from Jenkins, it works fine.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: seem like authentication issue

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer: [IP address of localhost:8080 -in webhooks of github +jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822898/ip-address-of-localhost8080-in-webhooks-of-github-jenkins)

"You need a public address for Github to point to when detected a push request. localhost is on your localmachine."

That answer explains how to setup ngrok which will give you a public IP and will allow you to setup your webhook.